# How to import hadoop mapreduce into eclipse for development

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to import the hadoop mapreduce source into eclipse so I can tinker with it.

The docs http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment here are great for getting hdfs set up in eclipse, but the steps for mapreduce just don't work (Select the hadoop-mapreduce-project directory as the root directory, Select the hadoop-mapreduce-project project -> But there is no mapreduce project to select).

Has anyone set this up to build cleanly?

Answer (score -1):

import the entire mapreduce directory with all subdirectory